# How to correct malformed HTML content due to quotation marks within a link

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs, looker-studio

I am using a code that adds a menu item to a Google Document and adds a link to a custom menu.  This all works correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

However, clicking on the menu item results in a `Malformed HTML content` error due to the quotation marks within the link itself.  This is the link in question:

> `https://lookerstudio.google.com/embed/reporting/**ID**/page/p_zc9uiw73dd?params=%7B"df22":"include%25EE%2580%25800%25EE%2580%2580IN%25EE%2580%2580Base%2520Line"%7D`

The link is to a Looker Studio report with a filter applied.  If I replace the link with https://google.com/ for example, everything works properly

I tried replacing the quotation marks with `&quot` in the URL.  The Looker Studio report displayed but the filter was not applied.  Is there another way to go about this?

**Code.gs**:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Scorecards')
      .addItem('Report','openUrl')
      .addToUi();
}

function openUrl(){
  var url = 'https://lookerstudio.google.com/embed/reporting/**ID**/page/p_zc9uiw73dd?params=%7B"df22":"include%25EE%2580%25800%25EE%2580%2580IN%25EE%2580%2580Base%2520Line"%7D';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Here are the error message details:

> Exception: Malformed HTML content: window.close =
> function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};var
> a = document.createElement("a");
> a.href="https://lookerstudio.google.com/embed/reporting/**ID**/page/p_zc9uiw73dd?params=%7B"df22":"include%25EE%2580%25800%25EE%2580%2580IN%25EE%2580%2580Base%2520Line"%7D";
> a.target="_blank";if(document.createEvent){ var
> event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
> if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}
> event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);}else{
> a.click() }close();Failed to open
> automatically. <a
> href="https://lookerstudio.google.com/embed/reporting/**ID**/page/p_zc9uiw73dd?params=%7B"df22":"include%25EE%2580%25800%25EE%2580%2580IN%25EE%2580%2580Base%2520Line"%7D"
> target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to
> proceed.google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410).

Note that I have replaced the Looker Studio ID with **ID** for privacy reasons.

Comment: What would that look like in the code?